# Selecting correlated records from database

Tags: sql-server

I've been improving my SQL knowledge but still failed to understand how to create some queries.

I have the following tables in a SQL Server database:

**User(id, name)**

**Loan(id_sender, id_receiver, amount, date, date_payment)**

What would be a valid query to:

1. Select the name of the users which have sent loans to another user both in 2014 and 2015
2. Select the pairs (id1, id2) of the users who have sent loans to each other

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

---

Edit 1:

My attempts:

1.

```
SELECT name FROM User WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id_sender FROM Loan WHERE
    id_receiver IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_receiver WHERE YEAR(date) = 2014) AND
    id_receiver IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_receiver WHERE YEAR(date) = 2015)
)
```

2.

```
SELECT id1, id2 FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT id_sender as id1 FROM Loan
    WHERE id_receiver IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT id_sender FROM Loan
        WHERE id_receiver = ???
    )
    (?)
)
```

Comment: What did you try so far. Add your attempt in question. We will try and fix it

Comment: Added them. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 1: In case your `date` column has an index, it's best to not use a function around the column so you can actually utilize the index.

```
SELECT name
FROM User
WHERE id IN (SELECT id_sender FROM Loan WHERE date >= '1/1/2014' AND date < '1/1/2015')
    AND id IN (SELECT id_sender FROM Loan WHERE date >= '1/1/2015' AND date < '1/1/2016')
```

Example 2: You can use a self join to find the matches using just the Loan table.

```
SELECT
    L1.id_sender AS id1,
    L1.id_receiver AS id2
FROM Loan L1
    INNER JOIN Loan L2
        ON L1.id_sender = L2.id_receiver
            AND L2.id_sender = L1.id_receiver
```

Answer (score 0):

1

```
SELECT name
FROM user
WHERE id EXISTS (
  Select Distinct id_sender 
  FROM loan 
  WHERE year(date) between 2014 and 2015
)
```

2

```
SELECT s.id1,s.id2, s.monto, p.nombre
FROM sap s INNER JOIN sop p
ON s.id1 = p.id_comun INNER JOIN sap a
ON a.id2 = p.id_comun
UNION
SELECT s.id1,s.id2, s.monto, p.nombre
FROM sap s INNER JOIN sop p
ON s.id1 = p.id_comun INNER JOIN sap a
ON a.id2 = p.id_comun
```